# Moment JS: Is it possible to handle dates of the format "21-Apr-2021"?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In my app, I receive dates with format like "21-Apr-2021". Is it possible to pass these to `moment()`? I'm trying with `moment("21-Apr-2021", "DD-MM-YYYY")`, but it says it's an invalid date. I know `moment()` expects dates in ISO 8601 format, but these dates are what are being returned from the API I'm using, so I'm wondering what the best way is to handle them.

Comment: May be you should do something like `moment("21-Apr-2021", "DD-MMM-YYYY")`

Comment: @Nithish This works, thanks! If you want to post as a solution then I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should do something like `moment("21-Apr-2021", "DD-MMM-YYYY")` as the date which you want to parse by moment is having `Apr` instead of `04` as month. For more info on [`string + format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) using moment.

```js
console.log(moment("21-Apr-2021", "DD-MMM-YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```